# Reusing variables when working with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to pull data from at least 3 databases, is there anything wrong with reusing my PDO objects?

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query1);

// do something

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host2 . ';dbname=' . $db_name2, $user2, $password2);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query2);

//do something else
```

Sorry for the edit but here's another consideration. With each of these I obviously should check whether or not the connection was successful and throw an exception if it wasn't:

```
if (!$dbh) {
    $err=$dbh->errorInfo();
    throw new Exception('Could not connect: ' . $err[2]);
}
```

I don't suppose there's a way to avoid this, unless I create all the connections at the same time and do `if (!dbh1|!dbh2) { ... }`. Just something else to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign `$dbh` to a `new PDO()` you are not technically reusing your pdo object. You are creating a new PDO instance and assigning it to a variable that you have previously used. There is nothing wrong with doing this as long as you understand what is occurring in your program.

**EDIT:**

I'm editing my answer to address the new question you've added to your previous question.

> With each of these I obviously should check whether or not the connection was successful and throw an exception if it wasn't:

You can surround your connection attempt in a try catch which is a typical strategy for dealing with connection errors:

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName', $userName, $password);

        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from TableName') as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }

        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        print "Error!: " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br />";
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: As I see it, the downside is the possibility for confusion but is there any advantage in terms of memory usage?

Comment: You are destroying the old object reference and thus are saving some very small amount of memory in your application. On the database side you might be saving as well as PDO will close connections when they are no longer used as this type of assignment allows the old PDO connection to the database to close.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but ... don't.  Use another variable name (they are cheap) it will make your code much easier to understand. Heck you can (should) even use variable names that will clue you in on what database your object is connecting to, ie:

```
// connection to data warehouse
$dbh_dataWH = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $user, $password);
// connection to crm 
$dbh_crm = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host2 . ';dbname=' . $db_name2, $user2, $password2);
```

This way you will be able to re-use your connection objects, and the code in my very humble opinion will be much clearer for you or anyone else that has to maintain it.

Comment: Yes. There is nothing wrong with re-using the same pdo object, per se. But it will get very confusing and messy if you need to re-use any of those conenections. A DB connection is not a costly perfomance matter. In other words, reusing the same variables in your application to save memory is over-optimisation. It is more important that your program  be easy to add functionality to, and even more important that it is easy to read and follow. How will you be sure 400 lines of code past those calls which DB your $dbh points to? In the end, it's all a matter of opinion. Happy coding,  friend.